# Smoothly removing animation from div

Tags: html, css, keyframe

I am using @keyframes to make an animation on a page which when scroll, attach the class to that div and animation take place, when I scroll back up. I am removing it. but when It is removed, it is abruptly. I want to make the animation to remove is a smooth manner just like it is being applied.

For demonstration purpose, I have attached a stripped version of my animation and [codepen](https://codepen.io/codearts/pen/bOVwLQ) link, in the animation when you get out of hover state, it is not smooth. How Can I make me animation to go to normal if I am not hovering?
HTML

```
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/250/250/animals" alt="">
</div>
```

css

```
.box{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #DDD1B9;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: rotate(80deg);
}
img{
transform: rotate(-80deg);
}
.box:hover{
  animation-name: hoverer , imx;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  height: 200px;
}
@keyframes hoverer{
  100%{
    width: 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
@keyframes imx{
  100%{
    background: black
  }
}
```

EDIT: The function is excerpt that add and remove divs are as following

```
  fixedHeader: function(event){
      const header = document.getElementsByClassName("logo")[0]
      this.y = event.clientY
      if(this.y >= 200){
          header.classList.add("fixed") //Add the div with animate
      }else if(this.y < 200){
          header.classList.remove("fixed") //Remove the div but animated back instead of abruptly 
      }
  }
```

Comment: use transition instead of animation

Comment: @TemaniAfif transitions are used for pusedo class but in my case, I am attaching and removing  class using javascript. The above is example of demostrate the sudden removing of it.

Comment: no, transtion is not only used with pseudo class, it works fine by adding/removing classes ... try and see (added an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use transtion like below:

```js
function change() {
  document.querySelector('.box').classList.toggle('fixed');
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background: #DDD1B9;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  transform: rotate(80deg);
  transition: 0.5s all;
}

img {
  transform: rotate(-80deg);
}

.box.fixed {
  width: 50%;
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  height: 200px;
  background: black
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/250/250/animals" alt="">
</div>

<button onClick="change()">toggle class</button>
```

Comment: That was example but in real, the div box get removed once you scroll the page. Adding is fine but when it is completely gone there is no class to apply animation too.

Comment: @Nofel `That was example but in real` --> you sould then share the *real* case because there is no generic solution and we can only asnwer the case you shared

Comment: I have added the except function

Comment: @Nofel same logic, my answer won't change simply used the class instead of hover .. check the update

Comment: Thanks, I thought transition only worked on pseudo classes.